# Order tracking, different url based on selected carrier

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shipment-tracking

I have added tracking link to default carrier by adding the following code to [mytheme]/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
    <tr <?php echo $i%2?'bgcolor="#F6F6F6"':'' ?>>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTitle()) ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="https://sporing.posten.no/sporing.html?q=<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?>" ><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

However.. my tablerate shipments are shipped with another carrier, and should have another url. How can I edit the above code to use different tracking url for tablerate shipments? I kind of know what to do, but not how to code it correctly...

But something like this (Pseduo code):

```
For each shipment;
 if shipment method is tablerate
   use tracking url http://my_tablerate_carrier+tracking number
 else if shipment method is all others
   use tracking url http://my_current_carrier+tracking number
```

All help appreciated, thanks